# HDMI Capture Card with pass through resolution higher than 4K

Tags: hdmi, multiple-monitors, video-capture

I have a Mac with an external monitor, I have it running at:

> Resolution: 6016 x 3384
>
> UI Looks like: 3008 x 1692 @ 60.00Hz

I have an HDMI capture card (it's actually a little external USB box) but it can only "pass through" at "4K @ 60.00Hz" (4096 × 2160).

I think I'd be ok at "capturing at 4K" but... I'd like to be able to "pass through at 6016 x 3384 but I can't find any hardware that supports that.

Does anyone know of any options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At that resolution, I think you have to start looking at Professional grade video capture cards. There's a company called BlackMagic Design that is pretty much the standard for these cards and they have some consumer friendly options. I would start looking at this https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/decklink, the Decklink 8K. It's an 8K capture card, and I believe it has monitor playback but I'm not sure that's exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did not know about BlackMagic cards. That's interesting. But yeah, it's not quite what I was looking for. I'm "capturing" this video on a laptop so I guess I'm not really looking for a card but some sort of external device. I don't have a desktop I can put a card in.